# Localhost URL works in browser but returns bool(false) for PHP curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

I have the following PHP code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec ($curl);

echo $html;
```

whith following result:

- OK for a $URL like "http://www.google.com"
- KO for a $URL like "http://localhost/index.html", and returning bool(false) when I do a var_dump

and this even though the browser can display http://localhost/index.html with no problem.
I am running a xampp apache server on the localhost.

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you definetly running this code from your localhost?

Comment: @fire Yes, I am running the code on the localhost.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.  If that works, it's a DNS issue.  If it doesn't work, there are a few other things it could be.  Try checking the CURL headers by setting the [`CURLOPT_HEADER`](http://us2.php.net/curl_setopt) option...  Also, set `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` to false for that check...

Comment: @tucson - How about run directly on command line `curl -v http://localhost/index.htm` ? (you download curl for windows, or wget for windows)

Comment: Take a look at your web server logs. What do they say for this access?

Comment: did you try curl_error()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @Floern  For $URL="http:\\127.0.0.1:8000\index.html"  I am getting: "Curl error: Could not resolve host: http:\127.0.0.1:8000\index.html; No data record of requested type"  Seems some backslash disappear in the process...

Comment: actually there should not be any backslash in the URL, forwardslashes are correct

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: please share complete code, including what / when you do a var_dump along with contents of http://localhost/index.html file - is it the standard xampp index.html file?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with index.html code? I guess there is any problem with your index.html file.

Answer (score 4):

You should make sure that your Apache listens on the correct interfaces. I had this problem once on a Vist machine: Apache (XAMP) was listening only on IPv4, but on Vista "localhost" resolves to an IPv6 address by default.

To disable the IPv6 address, edit you **%system32%\drivers\etc\hosts** file and remove the ::1 line.

Answer (score 0):

cURL might be converting the request to IPv6 behind the scenes. In addition to the solution suggested by xrstf, you may simply try to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to force a IPv4 connection.

Answer (score 0):

One Possible thing is a firewall issue. Curl by default tries to use port 1080, which is probably not open on your localhost / router / ISP.

If it's not an problem then try after your curl execution, put something like this :

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
```

You'll see what failed during your curl execution.
More info : [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) [curl_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
// ( see : www.php.net/curl_error )
```

To see whats happening, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This could be:

IPV6 issue with curl:

curl configured with: 
c-ares enabled 
ipv6 enabled 
local system got ipv6 disabled. Please check this.

You can also share the host file to get more details.